# Border after each row in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to make a `border-bottom` after each row using CSS grid with the content aligned to center. I can't get my head around it.

I want `.line` to fill the width of the entire `.wrapper` container.
How can I achieve that?

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto) max-content;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper>div:not(.line) {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.line {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>1111111</div>
    <div>222</div>
    <div>3333333333</div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div>4444</div>
    <div>555555555</div>
    <div>99999999999</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see a border between the first and second rows... how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: I Expect it to fill the entire 'wrapper' container

Comment: I have not tried it, but this article might be helpful: [Breaking Out With CSS Grid Layout](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/breaking-out-with-css-grid-layout/)

Comment: I just wanted to be able to put a border between rows in a grid, and the code in this question was helpful for that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of `justify-content` to center content you could add additional columns before and after your content, both with `1fr`.

Then position the first `div` and the `div` after `.line` to the start at the second column.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr8hL5dx/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, auto) 1fr;
}

.wrapper>div:not(.line) {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.wrapper > div:first-of-type,
.line + div {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.line {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>1111111</div>
    <div>222</div>
    <div>3333333333</div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div>4444</div>
    <div>555555555</div>
    <div>99999999999</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome man. I did it using <table> pushing the-content from both sides but felt somehow guilty not using css grid ;) Thanks mate !

Comment: I thought of doing this, but it doesn't seem very elegant to have a separate div for the border. However, since no other solution on this question that's more elegant than this has been suggested, and considering your high reputation, I am going to use this.

Comment: Depending on whats going on, I think the idea that there is a separation in a different div actually makes a lot of sense here - ie: it's a separator cell that's a line in an form entry layout, which is what I was looking for. It also meant I could use the grid-gap without having to margin or pad the cells.

Answer (score 1):

I had some success by using [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) and switching the line to a different type (`<span>`).

I also added a first and sixth column for the line to span,
while the other items only occupy column 2-5.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, auto) 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.wrapper>div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.line {
  grid-column: 1/6;
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>1111111</div>
    <div>222</div>
    <div>3333333333</div>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <div>4444</div>
    <div>555555555</div>
    <div>6666666</div>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <div>77777</div>
    <div>888888888</div>
    <div>99</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *responsive* solution that works with a *variable* number of items and without adding silly hard coded divs. Basically every item has a line below, the complicated part is determining the last row items which must not have a line. The example uses flex-box (and LESS) but that's not relevant here, it would also work with grid.

```
.grid {
    display: flex;
}
.grid-item{
    position: relative;
    .one-col{
        flex-basis: 100%/1;
        &:nth-last-child(1){
            &:after{ border-bottom: 0; }
        }
    }
    .two-cols{
        flex-basis: 100%/2;
        &:nth-last-child(1),
        &:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd){
            &:after{ border-bottom: 0; }
        }
    }
    .three-cols{
        flex-basis: 100%/3;
        &:nth-last-child(1),
        &:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+1),
        &:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+2),
        &:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(3n+1){
            &:after{ border-bottom: 0; }
        }
    }
    .four-cols{
        flex-basis: 100%/4;
        &:nth-last-child(1),
        &:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(4n+1),
        &:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(4n+2),
        &:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(4n+3),
        &:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(4n+1),
        &:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(4n+2),
        &:nth-last-child(4):nth-child(4n+1){
            &:after{ border-bottom: 0; }
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: @screen__sm) {
        .grid-item .one-col;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: @screen__sm) and (max-width: (@screen__md - 1)) {
        .grid-item .two-cols;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: @screen__md) and (max-width: (@screen__lg - 1)) {
        .grid-item .three-cols;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: @screen__lg) {
        .grid-item .four-cols;
    }

    &:after{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#uc_post_grid_elementor_aad741f.uc_post_grid_style_one .uc_post_grid_style_one_wrap {
    display: grid;
    position: relative !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#uc_post_grid_elementor_aad741f .ue_post_grid_item {
    position: static !important;
    overflow: visible;
}


#uc_post_grid_elementor_aad741f .ue_post_grid_item:nth-child(3n+1)::after {
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    width: 1080px;/Responsive with media query/
    max-width: 1024px !important;
    border: 1px solid #D3E6EA;
    color: #D3E6EA;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).